# A question about measurability on the Taylor expansion of Ito's formula.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am reading the proof of Itō's formula and self-studying stochastic integration.

Essentially, the authors proved the formula for dimension $d = 1$ and they ask the learner to do for greater generality (which is fine with me).

When they do dimension $d = 1,$ they do the following:

$$\begin{align*}
f(X_t) - f(X_0) &= \sum_{k = 1}^m [f(X_{t_k}) - f(X_{t_{k - 1}})]  \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^m f'(X_{t_{k - 1}})(X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}}) + \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 1}^m f''(\eta_k)(X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}})^2
\end{align*}$$
where $\eta_k$ is defined in the line $f(X_{t_k}) - f(X_{t_{k - 1}}) = f'(X_{t_{k - 1}})(X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}}) + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(\eta_k)(X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}})^2$ and therefore, it makes the $f(\eta_k)$ measurable on the set $\{X_{t_k} \neq X_{t_{k - 1}}\}$ and if $X_{t_k} = X_{t_{k-1}}$ we can choose $\eta_k = X_{t_{k - 1}},$ say. Fine, I understand their proof in dimension $d = 1.$ The problem comes when I am solving the problem of proving the same theorem for higher dimension. I would like to do the following Taylor's expansion (which, by the say, is the suggestion the authors give)
$$\begin{align*}
f(X_t) - f(X_0) &= \sum_{k = 1}^m [f(X_{t_k}) - f(X_{t_{k - 1}})]  \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^m \nabla f(X_{t_{k - 1}}) \cdot (X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}}) + \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 1}^m \mathbf{H}f (\eta_k) \cdot (X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k - 1}})^{(2)},
\end{align*}$$
where $\mathbf{H} f$ is the Hessian of $f$ and for any vector $h$ I write $h^{(2)} = (h, h).$

> The crux is, how to show $\eta_k$ can be chosen so that $\mathbf{H} f(\eta_k)$ is measurable or do you have an alternative approach?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896394/36150) which is quite similiar to yours.

Comment: Okay, I was assuming something very similar. I did know that $f(x + h) = T_{p - 1} f(x) \cdot h + \int\limits_0^1 dt\ \dfrac{(1 - t)^{p - 1} D^pf(v + th) \cdot h^{(p)}}{(p - 1)!} $ and I was thinking this shows some sort of measurability, but I actually cannot solve for $D^2f(\eta_k) = Hf(\eta_k)$ as you did before. However, I do have good news sort of, I did a draft and apparently you can use Taylor's theorem with _integral remainder_, as opposed to Lagrange's, and repeat almost verbatim the argument given in the book to prove Itō's formula.

Comment: I must add, by progressive measurability, the integral remainder is measurable. So, no issues there.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea (which I pointed out in my answer, which I linked, didn't I?)

Comment: The question is then, why people (I consulted several books) do not use the integral remainder?

Comment: I don't know; many authors/people simply don't care very much about measurability. The book by Schilling & Partzsch on Brownian motion does, for instance, use the integral remainder to prove the measurability (in the proof of Itô's formula).